# how to remove the /public folder from laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, public

I have laravel 9 running locally on windows (MAMP) and I want to open the home page with:

> localhost/myproject

instead of

> localhost/myproject/public

I tried to add **.htaccess** to the root folder with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and it didn't work! (I got 404),
(Although this worked with laravel 8!)

so what is the solution for this !? I spent hours on searching blogs and tweaking to no avail!
I also read on some discussions that using .htaccess or replacing the server.php and renaming it are NOT totally safe for production.

so what is the solution, and would this solution also work if I host my website online (for example on shared hosting) ?

THANKS

Comment: @pyrogrammer unfortunately no ...

Comment: In production, you'll point your server directly at the `public` directory. That's how Laravel's intended to be used. For local development, consider `php artisan serve`, Laravel Valet, or Laravel Sail. These handle this complexity for you; using something like XAMPP makes things harder.

Answer (score 2):

I have deployed several websites to hosting and vps servers with following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If error still occurs you may contact to your hosting provider and ask them to give you valid `.htaccess` rules. You may move your files inside public folder to root folder as well.

Comment: I am using MAMP and I tried the same code with laravel 8 project on the same machine and it worked .. with laravel 9 it is not working .. giving 404 error .. what other things do I need to check .. does the .htaccess file inside the public folder have to anything with it ?

Comment: Absolutely no. Does 404 page you have seen was laravel 404 template or that was generated by server?

Comment: It is a Laravel template (404 not found) ..
I worked it out with vhost like (test.local) and I set it to point to the public folder ..
but I am still annoyed about the .htaccess not working !! .... :(

Comment: If it is laravel 404 page then your .htaccess working perfectly. You have problem in application. Most probably in `routes`. If you are sure everything is quite right, then try to clear cache with `php artisan optimize`.

Comment: it is still the same problem, even running (php artisan optimize) will throw me an error (The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.) when I open the public page > solved by (php artisan route:clear) .. and the weird thing is that the project works without (npm run dev or build).. I'm frustrated ... :'( .. I didn't even find a solution on laracasts !

Comment: Actually there is no need to run `npm` for laravel project. Nginx should handle it in production

Answer (score 1):

Please beware of doing solutions like htacces and changing laravel core files in production, which will make your private files public.
there is a more secure way to do it.

#### Developments

```
use: `php artisan serve`
```

#### production

you can use Document Root to make the domain point to your project's public folder.

Answer (score -1):

To remove the public folder from laravel 9 you need to customize the .htaccess file.
You must have mod_rewrite enabled on your Apache server. The rewrite module is required to apply these settings. You also have enabled .htaccess in Apache virtual host for Laravel.

Update the code into your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, mod_rewrite is enabled, and I am using "MAMP" btw ..
and the same code worked for laravel 8 on the same environment!

Answer (score -1):

create a .htaccess in root directory

put these two line in it

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).